# Bootstrap thumbnails overlapping other elements on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a large form using bootstrap. I didn't use the `<form>` element however, as I organised input fields in various `<input>` inside thematic Bootstrap panels.

One of these panels uses a thumbnail as an input button to submit a user photo.
[image: Form with thumbail button]

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Biodata</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="personidphoto">ID Photo:</label>
                    <a class="thumbnail thumbnail-button" href="#">
                        <img src="blank_avatar.png" id="personidphoto">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="birthday">Birthdate:</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="birthday" min="1" max="31" placeholder="DD">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="birthmonth">&nbsp</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="birthmonth" min="1" max="12" placeholder="MM">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="birthyear">&nbsp</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="birthyear" min="1900" max="2015" placeholder="YYYY">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="gender">Gender:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="gender">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="medical">Notable medical condition(s):</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="medical">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've had to style the thumbnail to it to fit among from-groups.

```
a.thumbnail.thumbnail-button { 
    height: 108px;
    width: 108px;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Now the problem is: **when re-sizing the screen, the thumbnail then overlaps with the other form-group elements**.

[image: Thumbnail inside form overlapping with other elements.]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: If you down-vote, please explain why, otherwise people can't learn and improve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percentages instead of pixels for the image. Checkout this [codepen](http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/waVvXO).

CSS:

```
a.thumbnail.thumbnail-button {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

Your fixed width breaks your lay-out. When your width is in percentages, your width will scale with the page which solves your problem.

Comment: So I was focusing making the thumbnail fit nicely in height over 2 rows of input groups. I didn't realise it was conflicting with the layout more than anything. Thanks.

Comment: @Benjamin No problem. Good luck with the rest of your site!

Comment: Yep don't use a fixed width. Why not just put a img-responsive class to the <IMG> element width a min-height in CSS ?

Comment: @bep42 I don't understand. Please elaborate?

Comment: Checks http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive for the imv-responsive class. 

Btw, check this solution > http://jsfiddle.net/875t39jz/

Comment: @bep42 I see. I just prefer using CSS only without adding classes if it is not necessary.

Comment: I understand but img-responsive is a bootstrap class

Answer (score 1):

You have set a fixed `width` and `height` to the `.thumbnail-button`. So you need to:

```
a.thumbnail.thumbnail-button {
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}
```

And give the image, full width:

```
a.thumbnail.thumbnail-button img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

And give the `a.thumbnail.thumbnail-button`, a `grid` class:

```
<a class="thumbnail thumbnail-button col-md-2">
```

Comment: I don't understand why the `col-md-2` should be *inside* the `<a>` element. Shouldn't the `col-*-*` wrap the element instead? What's the difference?

Comment: `.col-md-*` has responsive widths.