# With Bootstrap 4, how to prevent form groups from overlapping on one another?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap 4 to create a Profile Edit form in my React app..

The form looks fine on a large display, but when on a small display like mobile, the `form-groups` are overlapping. See the problem image below, notice how the Profile Photo placeholder image is on top of First Name when it should be pushing First Name down and not overlapping.

Am I doing something wrong with the bootstrap Grid system or with form-groups?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9fpfxyo/

**CORRECT:**

[image]

**PROBLEM:**

[image]

code from JSFiddle:

```
<div class="container">
   <form>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="height: 100%;">
               <label for="files">Change your profile photo</label>
               <span>
                  <div class="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; background-color: rgb(29, 161, 242); background-image: url(&quot;https://abs.twimg.com/a/1498195419/img/t1/highline/empty_state/owner_empty_avatar.png&quot;); background-position: 50% center;">
                     <!-- react-text: 85 -->Try dropping some files.<!-- /react-text --><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" multiple="" style="display: none;">
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-block">Upload new Photo</button><!-- react-text: 88 --><!-- /react-text -->
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>First Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="first_name" value="XXX" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Last Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="last_name" value="XXX" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row justify-content-end">
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button></div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: mind explaining the difference? What I did wrong?

Comment: its overlapping due to `margin` issue so give the `margin-top:90px`

Comment: Thanks but isn't that just a hack?

Comment: so another any way ?? want ?? to fix ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kumarrishikesh12/bpvw37ed/ .. Check it Once !!

Comment: For your Reference check this Ans  .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32165107/bootstrap-thumbnails-overlapping-other-elements-on-smaller-screens

Answer (score 1):

I had this kinda issue a lot. the way i dealt with them is using media queries. Add a class to the right grid (col-lg-9 col-sm-12). And on smaller screens @media (min-width: 780px) give the class margin-top: 30px;

Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 1):

> **Set The Margin** OR Apply Css Code media width for mobile device and give the margin for it.

```
margin-top: 110px;
```

**Example:**

```
 <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 110px;">
               <label>First Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="first_name" value="XXX" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Last Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="last_name" value="XXX" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <form>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="height: 100%;">
               <label for="files">Change your profile photo</label>
               <span>
                  <div class="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size: 0px; margin-bottom: 1rem; background-color: rgb(29, 161, 242); background-image: url(&quot;https://abs.twimg.com/a/1498195419/img/t1/highline/empty_state/owner_empty_avatar.png&quot;); background-position: 50% center;">
                     <!-- react-text: 85 -->Try dropping some files.<!-- /react-text --><input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" multiple="" style="display: none;">
                  </div>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm btn-block">Upload new Photo</button><!-- react-text: 88 --><!-- /react-text -->
               </span>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 110px;">
               <label>First Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="first_name" value="XXX" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label>Last Name</label>
               <div><input type="text" name="last_name" value="XXX" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row row justify-content-end">
         <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button></div>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: also that doesn't work when the display is large, the margin is being used.

Comment: its overlapping due to margin issue so that give the `margin-top: 110px` from the form-group